# Why is html() returning undefined when I use jquery mobile's custom selector :jqmData()?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page, markup something like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="some_name">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 id="test">test</h1>
        </div>
further markup here
</div>
```

I want to reference the h1 element with the ID test in a Javascript function. I use the [recommended](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/) selector `:jqmData()` to get the header object.

```
var $page = $("some_name"),
    $header = $page.find("div:jqmData(role='header')");
```

From there I want to use find() to reference the h1 element.

Why does this not work:

```
$header.find("h1").html();
```

returns undefined,

but more conventional working solutions are easy to find:

```
$("body").find("h1".html();
$("#some_name").find("h1").html();
```

return "test" as expected.

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/w2ZR6/1/

Comment: note: `var $page = $("some_name"),` you forgot hashtag `#some_name`.

Comment: I couldn't see it for looking! Thanks.